# Firebase query charges additional reads?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How does `firebase` query works?

for example, if i write this query,

```
 var collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('collection')
      .where(cond)
      .where(cond2)
      .where(cond3);
```

So is this gonna return only the documents which fit the conditions?
AND I AM GOING TO GET CHARGED ONLY FOR THOSE DOCUMENT READS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)  TL:DR

Charges for reads have some nuances that you should keep in mind. The following sections explain these nuances in detail.
Listening to query results

Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get realtime updates when the query results change.

When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.
Managing large result sets

Cloud Firestore has several features to help you manage queries that return a large number of results:

> Cursors, which allow you to resume a long-running query.

> Page tokens, which help you paginate the query results.

> Limits, which specify how many results to retrieve

> Offsets, which allow you to skip a fixed number of documents.

There are no additional costs for using cursors, page tokens, and limits. In fact, these features can help you save money by reading only the documents that you actually need.

However, when you send a query that includes an offset, you are charged a read for each skipped document. For example, if your query uses an offset of 10, and the query returns 1 document, you are charged for 11 reads. Because of this additional cost, you should use cursors instead of offsets whenever possible.
Queries other than document reads

For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed for one document read. If fetching the complete set of results requires more than one request (for example, if you are using pagination), you are billed once per request.
Minimum charge for queries

There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.